# Transition property doent works when initial value used

Tags: css

I want to create some animated menu, where you hover over image and see description od it, but some problems occured.

- animation goes instantly when initial value is used;
- at the start text located under image, instead of being on the right
  side.

There is my code:

```css
body{
  text-align:center;
}
div{
  display:inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  transition:0.5s;
  font-size:20px;
}
div:hover{
  width:initial;
  overflow:visible;
  transition:2s;
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
}
img{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d9/Test.png"/> Some text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d9/Test.png"/> Some text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d9/Test.png"/> Some text</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `initial` is like `auto`...you can't transition to it. For that matter, you can't transition `overflow` either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`initial` is like `auto`...you can't transition to it.

You could use `max-width` instead.

Also. note that `overflow` cannot be transitioned so you'll have that issue too.

```css
body{
  text-align:center;
}
div{
  display:inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
  max-width:80px;
  height:80px;
  transition:0.5s;
  font-size:20px;
}
div:hover{
  max-width:100%;
  overflow:visible;
  transition:2s;
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
}
img{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d9/Test.png"/> Some text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d9/Test.png"/> Some text</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d9/Test.png"/> Some text</span>
  </div>
</body>
```